# How to convert C# DateTime to AngularJs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

In the AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), an example was shown:

```
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span>:
    <span>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span>:
   <span>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</span>:
   <span>{{'1288323623006' | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</span>:
   <span>{{'1288323623006' | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</span><br>
```

What are the values on the left of the filter (1288323623006)? How to convert C# DateTime to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1, 1970, and the specific date and time.
In javascript you can get current time value using `Date.now` function

```
var currentTime = Date.now();
```

Angularjs date format can work with both time representation and `Date` object. So you don't need to convert `DateTime` to number on the server side, just use DateTime and convert it to `Date` object on client side.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evez0a6g/)

If you really need number on the server side you can use code below

```
public static class DateTimeJavaScriptExtensions
{
   private static readonly long DatetimeMinTimeTicks =
      (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).Ticks;

   public static long ToJavaScriptMilliseconds(this DateTime dt)
   {
      return (long)((dt.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the filter at angular side so that it will convert into date format

```
app.filter("dateFilter", function () {
    return function (item) {
        if (item !== null) {
            return new Date(parseInt(item.substr(6)));
        }
        return "";
    };
});
```

And html side you have right like this

```
<td data-title="'Booking Date'" sortable="'Booking Date'" filter="{ 'booking_date': 'text' }">{{Booking.booking_date|dateFilter | date:"dd-MM-yyyy" }}</td>
```