# How to get the date of server on which the site is deployed on?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the current date of server on which site is deployed on... our site is deployed on IIS and the system is in America. when we open URL,on date column it shows our current date i.e: my system current date

Comment: Given that you've tagged ASP.NET MVC, could you just create an API (like) endpoint that just returns the current server time?

Comment: @phuzi no we cannot create Api for now. we are getting current date function in angular js and it returns the system current date

Comment: You don't necessarily need a full API, just a single action in a controller that returns a `JsonResult` or even just a raw string

Comment: @phuzi yes something like that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469187/how-to-convert-c-sharp-datetime-to-angularjs/27469661#27469661

Comment: Ah, I think I got the wrong end of the stick... _"on date column it shows our current date"_ this likely because the server is "correctly" serializing the date and time to an ISO-8601 formatted string and the browser (Angular/JavaScript) is parsing the string as a date and automatically converting it to the user's local timezone. Can you confirm what you're receiving from the server?

Comment: Could you also confirm you're seeing in the browser vs. what you expect to see?

Comment: i'm seeing local time in browser but i want to see the time of server

Comment: DateTime is stored on any computer using UTC.  The string results is automatically converted to local time using the local machine Timezone.  If you are getting local than the Timezone on the server is set wrong.